# What is the best practice to use LUIS for dialog interruption

Tags: c#, botframework

The Core-Bot example (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot) shows a way to handle interruptions, e.g. when a user types 'help' or 'cancel' in the middle of a dialog.  It uses a literal text compare for it:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, 
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
  {
    var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

    switch (text)
    {
      case "help":
      case "?":
        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Show Help...",
          cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
      case "cancel":
      case "quit":
        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Cancelling", 
          cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to use LUIS for determining whether a user tries to interrupt the current dialog by checking for the Help intent for example.

The problem is that I don't want to do the call to LUIS twice (i.e. first to check if it's an interruption, and second to get the intent when the dialog continues), and I can't pass the recognizer result to the dialog via the OnContinueDialogAsync() method.

```
var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
if (result != null)
{
    return result;
}

return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
```

I think it's possible to only make the call only once, and then store the recognition result in the user state using state accessors, but it feels like a work around to me.

What is the recommended way of using LUIS for interruptions and in the dialogs?

Comment: You could achieve the desired outcome by updating the `ExecuteLuisQuery` method in `LuisHelper`to handle the "help" intent. That way you could do away with the interrupt stuff.

I'm not sure why you want to avoid the two LUIS calls as the amount of overhead is quite trivial. Perhaps you could provide more information about your scenario which outlines why you want to reduce the numbers of calls? I would wager that you will run into many more issues down the line and end up adding unnecessary complexity to your application by trying to cache the LUIS results to avoid making an extra API call.

Comment: You are right that it probably isn't noticeably slower to have two LUIS calls. However it is a paid service, and with this construction you are making almost twice as many calls as required. 
Also, every sentence, except the ones which are caught by the interrupter, will be received by LUIS twice. Since there is AI behind it, I worry this could trip up the machine learning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this with Redis Cache.

I'd create an Interrupt Dialog, which can be inherited by any dialog that I need to enable interruptions. In this dialog, instead of doing a literal text compare, i'd call LUIS recognizer, which will return the intent.

```
protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var result = await InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
    if (result != null)
    {
        return result;
    }

    return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
}


private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var luisResult = await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync<MyLuisModel>(innerDc.Context, cancellationToken);
        switch (luisResult.TopIntent().intent)
        {
            case MyLuisModel.Intent.Cancel:
                return await CancelAllDialogsAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);

            case MyLuisModel.Intent.SignOut:
                return await SignOutAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then, in the recognizer class, I can cache LUIS Result for each utterance. You have to make sure that you clear the cache each time you re-publish the LUIS model, or have a smaller cache expire time.

```
public virtual async Task<T> RecognizeAsync<T>(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : IRecognizerConvert, new()
{
    var utterance = turnContext.Activity?.AsMessageActivity()?.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(utterance)) return default;
    var cacheKey = Regex.Replace(utterance, @"[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "_");
    var matches = Regex.Match(cacheKey, @"[A-Za-z0-9]+");
    if (!matches.Success) return default;
    cacheKey = "MyBot_" + cacheKey + "_" + nameof(T);

    var recognizerResult = await _cacheClient.Db15.GetAsync<T>(cacheKey);

    if (recognizerResult != null) return recognizerResult;

    recognizerResult = await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync<T>(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    await _cacheClient.Db15.AddAsync(cacheKey, recognizerResult, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

    return recognizerResult;
}
```